# cannot add youtube player fragment to layout

Tags: android-fragments, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add youtubeplayersupportfragment to a layout inside my fragment.
while adding the fragment to layout it says
"cannot convert youtubeplayersupportfragment to fragment.
here is my code

```
public class combofrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_combofrag, container, false);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_view1, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                player.loadVideo("mI8HWnkWk7c");
                player.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

there is an error on this line

```
transaction.add(R.id.youtube_view1, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `child fragment manager` is of type `android.app.FragmentManager` while your `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`  is of type `android.support.v4(or v7 etc).app.Fragment` . you cannot cast `fragment` to `support fragment` .

change your `combofrag` to `support fragment` or your `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`  to `fragment` to resolve this conflict.

I will prefer to go with`support fragment` instead of use just `fragment`.

Hope this will help.